# pyfirmata is reading analog values but the if-else statement are proving it otherwise

Tags: python, firebase, arduino

So I've got a python script that reads sensor data from Arduino and stores it in the Firebase database. The program was working well until I added some if-else statement and now it looks like the values are being treated as Nonetype I'm stuck kindly help.

Here's the code:

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
import time
board = Arduino('COM3')

from firebase import firebase

firebase=firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/",None)
it = util.Iterator(board)
it.start()
analog_input1 = board.get_pin('a:0:i')
analog_input2 = board.get_pin('a:1:i')
analog_input3 = board.get_pin('a:2:i')
analog_input4 = board.get_pin('a:3:i')
state="null"

while True:
    analog_value1 = analog_input1.read()
    analog_value2 = analog_input2.read()
    analog_value3 = analog_input3.read()
    analog_value4 = analog_input4.read()
    if analog_value1>=2000 or analog_value2>=23 or analog_value3>=23 or  analog_value4>=3000:
        state="Slightly Alarming"
    elif analog_value1>=4000 or analog_value2>=31 or analog_value3>=31 or  analog_value4>=4000:
        state="Alarming"
    elif analog_value1>=5000 or analog_value2>=50 or analog_value3>=50 or  analog_value4>=5000:
        state="Danger!"
    else:
        state="Normal"
    firebase.post('/xxxxx/',{'MQ4':analog_value1,'MQ7':analog_value2,'MQ9':analog_value3,'MQ135':analog_value4,'Status':state})
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: "it looks like the values are bein treated as Nonetype"  what makes you think that? are there any error messages you'd like to share? did you remove the if statement and see if it works again? usually read() returns None if there is something wrong on the Arduino side.

Comment: that's the main error I've been getting " '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' " I've tried to print the data and it seemed to print the analog values obtained by the sensors

Comment: it seemed to print??? either it does or it does not

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous answer yes it does print the values